# Ошибка с базой данных sqlite flask (python)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

Писал по видео Гоши Дудраря и не понимаю где ошибка?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///shop.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    isActive = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text(500), nullable=True)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 868, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 839, in _call_for_binds
    engine = self.engines[key]
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 628, in engines
    app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

Comment: У меня запустилось python src.py База shop.db - создалась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что метод create_all объекта db будет работать только в контексте приложения. Поэтому вместо этого:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Напишите это:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: У меня не создается файл с базой данных, так и должно быть?